# thread break 1.1 at NSJSONSerialization in swift 2

Tags: json, multithreading, serialization, crash, swift2

hi guys im learning swift tutorial these days and currently working on how to work with php and mysql with swift. anyway i managed upto save data in mysql database . somehow i could get a json object with the return message to swift but when i going to use "NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData" to get actual data then app gonna crash.

here is the code snippet so far :

```
NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data , response, error ) -> Void in

        let dataContent = data! as NSData

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){

            if error != nil{
                self.displayAlertMessage(error!.localizedDescription);
                return
            }

            print("error + \(error)" )

            print(data) // actually up to this level the code works

            do {
                //let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data! , options: .MutableContainers ) as? NSDictionary;

                // here thread gonna crash and shows : "Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" message with green line

                var json = try  NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dataContent , options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary


                print(json)

                if let parseJSON:NSDictionary = json{
                    let userId = parseJSON["userId"] as? String

                    if userId != nil{

                        var myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration Successful", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){(action) in

                            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil )
                        }
                    }else {

                        let errorMessage = parseJSON["message"] as? String
                        if(errorMessage != nil ){

                            self.displayAlertMessage(errorMessage!)

                        }
                    }

                }


            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("json error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }

        }

    }).resume()
}
```

im stucked at "try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData" line. can anyone help me to solve this thing?

thanks all for your great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says thread break 1.1, that means you have a breakpoint set and the debugger is pausing on that line.  If you look at the breakpoint navigator (command-7 is the shortcut) do you see a breakpoint for that line of code?  There is also probably a little blue arrow in the gutter of the editor by the line number.

Comment: that worked mate. i thought something wrong with the code... thanks for the explaining